# Sequel Pro Combine Multiple lines where only 1 column is different but the rest are the same

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I have a table of meals and there are several id's associated with other tables on the main table.

I have another table where the ingredients for the meals are listed by ids so that I don't have to type the ingredients over and over. But when I run the following search, I get the meal name, listed multiple times because each ingredient is listed on it's own line. How can I get it to display the name, and then all the ingredients on the same line?

```
SELECT
    mealName, ingredient, quantity 
FROM 
    meals, mealTotal, ingredients 
WHERE 
        mealTotal.mealId = meals.MealId 
    and mealTotal.ingredientId =  ingredients.ingredientId  
ORDER BY 
    mealName;
```

currently shows:

```
Apple Pie    Apple    1
Apple Pie    Tabantha Wheat    1
Apple Pie    Goat Butter       1
Apple Pie    Cane Sugar    1
```

What I want it to show:

```
Apple Pie    Apple   1    Tabantha Wheat    1      Goat Butter    1    Cane Sugar    1
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.   *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to return all the ingredients and quantities as a list. So starting with the already existing query, you'd convert it to:

```
-- Concatenate all your (ingredient, quantity)
SELECT
    mealName, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(ingredient_and_quantity ORDER BY ingredient_and_quantity SEPARATOR '\t' ) AS ingredient_list
FROM
    (SELECT
        mealName, ingredient, quantity, 
        CONCAT(ingredient, ' ', quantity) AS ingredient_and_quantity
    FROM 
        meals
        JOIN mealTotal ON mealTotal.mealId = meals.mealId
        JOIN ingredients ON ingredients.ingredientId = mealTotal.ingredientId 
    ) AS q
ORDER BY 
    mealName;
```

This is going to give you a *string* with all the ingredients and corresponding quantities.

```
mealName  | ingredient_list                                                         
:-------- | :-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Apple Pie | Apple 1        Cane Sugar 1        Goat Butter 1        Tabantha Wheat 1
```

Note that I have changed your *implicit* `JOIN`s to *explicit* ones. (Implicit `JOIN`s are more difficult to read and error-prone, it's easy you miss one link-condition on the `WHERE` and you get a carteasian product you weren't expecting).

You can check all this at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5d49235e9ea43337035a4e6e6fc18d29)*

---

If you want to have the list of ingredients as different columns `(ingredient_1, quantity_1, ingredient_2, quantity_2, ...)`, then you can start from a variation of this query, and *decompose* the grouped data using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
-- Pivot 
SELECT
    mealName, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ingredients, ',',  1), ',', -1) AS ingredient_1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ingredients, ',',  2), ',', -1) AS ingredient_2,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ingredients, ',',  3), ',', -1) AS ingredient_3,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ingredients, ',',  4), ',', -1) AS ingredient_4,

    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(quantities, ',',  1), ',', -1) AS quantity_1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(quantities, ',',  2), ',', -1) AS quantity_2,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(quantities, ',',  3), ',', -1) AS quantity_3,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(quantities, ',',  4), ',', -1) AS quantity_4
FROM
    (SELECT
        mealName, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(ingredient ORDER BY ingredient SEPARATOR ',') AS ingredients,
        GROUP_CONCAT(quantity ORDER BY ingredient SEPARATOR ',') AS quantities
    FROM
        (SELECT
            mealName, ingredient, quantity
        FROM 
            meals
            JOIN mealTotal ON mealTotal.mealId = meals.mealId
            JOIN ingredients ON ingredients.ingredientId = mealTotal.ingredientId 
        ORDER BY
            mealName, ingredient
        ) AS q
    ) AS q2
ORDER BY 
    mealName;
```

That would give you something like:

```
mealName  | ingredient_1 | ingredient_2 | ingredient_3 | ingredient_4   | quantity_1 | quantity_2 | quantity_3 | quantity_4
:-------- | :----------- | :----------- | :----------- | :------------- | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :---------
Apple Pie | Apple        | Cane Sugar   | Goat Butter  | Tabantha Wheat | 1.01       | 1.04       | 1.03       | 1.02
```

You can check this at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5bbfc4873833b70e1f6b1d150469efc8)*

Note that this doesn't scale (if you need 10 columns, you'll have to do it by hand), and that some values might get repeated, because of the way `STRING_INDEX` works. I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Comment: Ultimately what I plan on doing is using the query to pull the information into  a program. I'm new to coding and such, and just working in a console window of C# for now. So I'm looking to take the into and put the ingredient and the number into a dictionary? for that particular meal. Then When i want, I will be able to display the ingredient and quantity for that ingredient back to the user.

Hope that helps a bit with understanding better how to query it from the database.

Comment: If you wanted to retrieve values and put them into a dictionary using C#, *you would have got the proper response if you have just asked that*. Actually, you were already doing the right thing, you just need to loop through your recordset, and add items to your dictionary.